# Start a scrapy spider TypeError: object.__new__(thread.lock) is not safe, use thread.lock.__new__()

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy on CentOS,python 2.7.3 under virtualenwrapper,when I start a spider an error occurs`TypeError: object.__new__(thread.lock) is not safe, use thread.lock.__new__()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient(DB_URL)
```

in settings.py,move it to pipelines.py.Then spider works.
more details https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1325#event-344876982